# Proving $\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x)^3} dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

To prove: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x)^3} dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} dx$$

I don't know how to integrate these integrals.  I tried integration by parts and it doesn't get me through.  How can i prove this?

Comment: Use integration by parts

Comment: I tried it but since the limits is infinite I'm not sure how to proceed further. Can u write the solution

Comment: What is $\lim _{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{(1+x)^2}$?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to include your attempt and point precisely where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, let
$$I=2\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x)^3} dx - \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{x-1}{(1+x)^3}dx. $$
Now
$$I\overset{x\to\frac1x}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\frac1x-1}{(1+\frac1x)^3}\frac{dx}{x^2}=\int_0^\infty\frac{1-x}{(1+x)^3}dx=-I$$
and hence $I=0$.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of integration is quite easy if you know Beta Gamma functions

In one of its forms
$$
\beta(m,n)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{m-1}}{(1+t)^{m+n}} dt
$$

So the given integrals are $\beta(2,1)$ and $\beta(1,1)$
$$\beta(m,n)=\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}$$

For an integer m

$\Gamma(m)=(m-1)!$

So the question simplifies to
$$\frac{1!0!}{2!} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{0!0!}{1!}$$

There is good further reading in NP.Bali Real analysis if u want to check it out

You could also use by parts by taking limits but its basically reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{(1+x)^3}dx=\int_0^{\infty} x\ast \frac{1}{(1+x)^3}dx=\int_0^{\infty} u\ast v^{'}=u\ast v\Bigg|_0^{\infty} -\int_0^\infty u^{'}\ast v = x\ast (-\frac{1}{2(1+x)^2})\Bigg|_0^{\infty} -\int_0^\infty1\ast (-\frac{1}{2(1+x)^2})dx=0-\int_0^{\infty} -\frac{1}{2(1+x)^2}dx=
\\ =\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx  \blacksquare$

Comment: My signal processing dumb self saw convolution all around!

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{l}\displaystyle\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}^3}}}dx} ,\left\{ \begin{array}{l}u = x\\dv = \frac{{dx}}{{{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}^3}}}\end{array} \right. \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}du = dx\\v =  - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}^2}}}\end{array} \right.\\ \displaystyle\Rightarrow \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}^3}}}dx}  = \left. { - \frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}^2}}}} \right|_0^\infty  + \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}^2}}}dx} \\\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}^2}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{1}{{x{{\left( {1 + \frac{1}{x}} \right)}^2}}} = 0 \Rightarrow \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}^3}}}dx}  = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}^2}}}dx} \end{array}$$

Comment: What is wrong with downvote?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac 12 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx$$
Considering $u=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$, $v=1$,

$$\frac 12 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx$$
$$=\frac 12 \left[\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}+2\int\frac{x}{(1+x)^3}dx\right]_0^\infty$$
$$=\frac 12 \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}+\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{(1+x)^3}dx$$ Using LHospitals rule on the limits problem, we get it to be $0$.
Hence,
$$\frac 12 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{(1+x)^3}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{(1+x)^3} d x & =-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} x \,d \left[\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\right] \\
& =-\left[\frac{x}{2(1+x)^2}\right]_0^{\infty}+\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d x}{(1+x)^2} \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d x}{(1+x)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$